# saving bitmap from android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

im building my own camera app using the camera api. I have a few problems. First im taking the picture at a resolution 1944 x  2592. When i save the image i get a resolution of 960 by 960. This only happens when i use FileOutputStream to save the picture to a folder. When i use MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() to save it to the gallery i get a picture that's  1944 x  2592, which is what i need.  How can i save using FileOutputStream while keeping the 1944 x  2592 resolution?  Second how can i add in the details for the picture i just saved? like the height and width etc.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "testing ", "");
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `Bitmap` in the first place? You are handed the `byte[]` of JPEG data in `onPictureTaken()` -- just save that. "how can i add in the details for the picture i just saved?" -- add details to what? The JPEG image knows its height and width. If you are looking to add other EXIF headers to the JPEG file, you can [use `ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html).

Comment: i did just save the byte[] but the resolution changes

Comment: "i did just save the byte[] but the resolution changes" -- not according to the code in your question. There, you are saving a `Bitmap`, in the first two lines of the code snippet.